# KML Layer is not shown in Google Maps

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, kml

I have a problem with displaying certain KMLs in Google Maps, it happens that after going through the method addLayerToMap, it is not rendered on the map.

Funny is that when I step it in Google MyMaps the same works normally and even if I export from there and set to display in Google Maps of the application, it displays normally.

I noticed that MyMaps greatly changes the structure of the KML and it is even smaller (in number of lines and consequently the size).

KML file (original): https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Z4AZMP1xNMgVNNXjK11-kD0gwlPLmJmR/view?usp=sharing

PS: On invalid paths of images, I changed manually and there were no results.

KML file (parsed by Google MyMaps): https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WPT3ZogzjTNa9ITeZze1cYf3ly4JFpUZ/view?usp=sharing

Method that I'm using to read KML (works with most of the KMLs I tried, including Google's own example):

```
private void retrieveFileFromResource() {
    try {
        KmlLayer kmlLayer = new KmlLayer(mMap, R.raw.teste3, getActivity());
        kmlLayer.addLayerToMap();
        moveCameraToKml(kmlLayer);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I'm trying to add the components to the map manually (polylines, polygons, markers, etc) but did not succeed.

Comment: Check to have HTTP auth enabled on the server. This could prevent google from requesting the KML file.

Comment: But the file I'm testing is local in the "res/raw" folder.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Maps API cannot access KML (or GeoRSS) files from local drives.  They need to be online, at a publicly accessible URL.

Comment: Did you manage to solve it? I have the same problem also with local KML files

Answer (score 0):

try using the below code to check if the kml file is present in the folder and if present, show them in the google maps.

```
private void retrieveFileFromResources()
{
try
{
int check = this.getResources().getIdentifier(teste3,"folder name", this.getPackageName());
if(check != 0)
{
InputStream inputstream = this.getResources().openRawResource(this.getResources().getIdentifier(teste3,"folder name",this.getPackageName()));
KmlLayer kmlLayer = new KmlLayer(mMap, inputStream, getApplicationContext());
kmlLayer.addLayerToMap();
}
else
{
Toast.makeText(this,"Request KML Layer not available",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}catch(IOException e)
{
e.printStackTrace();
}
catch(XmlPullParseException e)
{
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```